# CSRF_TOKEN Validation Failed in Django even it is included in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-csrf, csrf-token

Hi I'm new to Django and struggling with Django and `csrf_token` is getting `403 forbidden error` even its included in the form template can some one explains me what's the issue here I have searched for answers but none worked for me when I inspect I can see the csrf token in the form Thanks In advance

```html
template.html
    
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<form action="{% url 'newPage'%}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

```py
# urls.py
    
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:name>", views.title, name="title"),
    path("search/", views.search , name="search"),
    path("NewPage/", views.newpage, name="newPage")
]
```

```py
# views.py
    
def newpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.POST()
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
           title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
           content = form.cleaned_data.get('content')
           util.save_entry(title,  f'# {title}\n\n{content}')
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('encyclopedia:title'))
        else:
           form = newEntry()
           return render(request, "encyclopedia/newentry.html", { "form": form })
    else:
       form = newEntry()
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/newentry.html", { "form": form })
```

Comment: Please try to restart the server and run in another port as `python manage.py runserver 4000` and hard refresh it through `Ctrl+f5`.

Comment: Can you also share the full error traceback?

Comment: Try to maintain gap between `'% }`  so write it as `{% url 'newPage' %}` inside action.